# Cannot edit numbers document with AppleScript

Tags: numbers, applescript

I am trying to run a very simple script in automator for a the apple program numbers. I have tried a couple of different scripts with no success.

With the following code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Numbers"
        activate

        tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to set the value of cell "B3" to 0
        tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to set the value of cell "C4" to 42

    end tell

    return input
end run
```

I get the following error message:

"Numbers got an error: Can’t set cell "B3" of sheet 1 of document 1 to 0."

There was a nearly identical posted question with the following solution:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Numbers"
  tell table 1 of sheet 3 of document 1
    set the value of cell 1 of column "E" to 1000
  end tell
end tell

    return input
end run
```

but this gives me the following error message:

"Numbers got an error: Can’t set table 1 of document 1 to 1000."

This other post did mention it may have something to do with privileges but did not elaborate and I have been unable to find any more information regarding this.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With a **Numbers** *document* already opened, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell first table of first sheet of front document
        set value of cell "B3" to 0
        set value of cell "C4" to 42
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Here is a different way of saying the same thing as the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    set value of cell "B3" of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1 to 0
    set value of cell "C4" of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1 to 42
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: This has worked for. Maybe it was an issue with pointing to "document" and not "front document". Thank you very much for your timely response and help.

Comment: @Michael Szabo, The issue with the first _block_ of _code_ in your question is it's missing `table`, e.g. `first table` or `table 1` and they are the same just two different ways of saying the same thing, as `front document` and `document 1`. The second _block_ of _code_ would only work if there was a third _sheet_ in `document 1` with a _table_. For me, the second _block_ of _code_, as is, with only one _sheet_ it errors with: "**error** "Numbers got an error: Can’t get sheet 3 of document 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from sheet 3 of document 1" If I change `sheet 3` to `sheet 1` it works.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You may know the answer to this. Is there anyway to add a checkbox and a script for show/hide rows in the Numbers App for iPhone or iPad? I can't seem to find information anywhere regarding this.